# What happens when dynamically execute single DFP adcode in a same page

Tags: javascript, google-dfp, ads

I am trying to implement DFP ad execution in between my comment module. So same DFP ad unit executes dynamically in the same page in between comments. If I use same ad unit multiple times, does it cause any issues? Can I load same DFP ad unit in different 'DIV' tag without any problem? Kindly give me a clear idea on these questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest (while maybe not the best) solution is to use the DFP passback code option. Then you can execute same Ad Unit as many times as you want.